# How to show ImageTarget's feature points on AR camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, arcamera

I want to show the feature points of image targets on AR camera while scanning the image using unity tool. Is there any script or any option to achieve that?.

I have attached the screenshot of showing image feature like that I want to show on AR camera.

[image: Image from vuforia target manager]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no such option. Vuforia is not exposing this information, and it is not supported in any API. 
I did see, however, someone mentions he was able to do it by parsing the binary '.dat' file of the dataset - but I do not think it is something you can rely on (and Vuforia also do not encourage such usage). You can take a look here: [Feature Points](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/debug-information-feature-points)